# Disable all checkboxes when one active

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

My problem is that i dont know which element i should target to check if the checkbox is checked and then to disable the other ones. Do i need put this code inside the form tag?
In my code i have 2x2 checkboxes 2 for the yes answer and 2 for the no answer.

thas my HTML:

```
<div id="form">
<div class="anketa">
    <h3>Pači sa Vám táto stránka?</h3>
    <div class="checkbox custom">
        <input id="box" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="boxes" />
        <label for="box" class="css-label" name="yes" onclick="" ></label> Áno
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox custom">
        <input id="box1" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="boxes" />
        <label for="box1" class="css-label" name="no" onclick="" ></label> Nie
    </div>
</div>

<div class="anketa">
    <h3>Pomohla Vám táto stránka?</h3>
    <div class="checkbox custom">
        <input id="box2" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="boxes" />
        <label for="box2" class="css-label" name="yes" onclick=""></label>Áno
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox custom">
        <input id="box3" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="boxes" />
        <label for="box3" class="css-label" name="no" onclick=""></label> Nie
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is my script:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementByClassName("css-checkbox");
//?
}
```

Thanks for every help.

Comment: You fine with jquery?

Comment: thx but not really :D want to use javascript...thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using radio buttons instead, they will only let the user select one answer per question at the time.

Example:

```
(Question 1)
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="yes" />
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="no" />

(Question 2)
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="yes" />
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="no" />
```

If the user selects "yes" on question 1 and "no" on question 2 the values sent to the server will be:

```
question1=yes&question2=no
```

Comment: Thx the radio buttons are fine ... for now... but what if i need to use checkboxes.

Comment: Checkboxes are for multiple choice, if you want the user to be able to select 0 to all alternatives, checkboxes are the way to go, if you want the user to only be able to select 0 or 1 alternative, use radio buttons.

Comment: Ok thx a lot. Now i changed the type from checkbox to radio. But it takes as four radio buttons :D

Comment: The name attribute should be different for each question, that way, each button will only reset the other buttons within its own question.

Comment: Also, the radio buttons should have a value attribute, then the selected button's value attribute will be sent to the server if you submit the form

Comment: yes i want to send  values to the server and store it in database.

Comment: Edited post, this should give you an idea on how the radio buttons submit data.

Comment: Hi TRGWII pls can u help me with some CSS?

Comment: what's up? (I think this should be in a separate question?)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, please explain further in a new question, the comments aren't great for explaining a big problem

Comment: ok thank you i can try to post new question...but i think a i have too messy code :)